# how to use regex in alias?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, alias

I want to create the alias for the command "ssh user@10.32.44.225" as 10.32.44.225

```
alias [0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]="ssh user@$0"
```

I have created it, but it is not working. Is there any syntax error in this command?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? As described, it does not make much sense. (There can not be a space before the `=`, and the name may need to be quoted, but I do not think that solves it.)

Comment: Instead of typing the command "ssh user@ip", I want to type only the command "ip".

Comment: That's `alias ip='ssh user@ip'`. But it looks like you mean something like "Instead of "ssh user@127.0.0.1", you want to type the IP address after the `@`? If that's what you look for, please edit the question to explain that.

Comment: This cannot be done with aliases. Also, even if it could, your proposed ranges include a large number of invalid IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable - even with `alias`, though the only way I know would involve `eval` which can be dangerous depending on what the arguments might contain - but not with regex. The real problem here is *tokenization* - for each simple command the shell reads in it attempts to execute whatever *word* it finds in *command position* as an alias first, then. failing that, as a function/builtin, and, failing both of those, as a `$PATH`ed executable. This is a simplification of the process, but it is pretty close to the truth.

The problem is that you have in a single *word* two possible *tokens* - `ssh` is what you'd like to execute, and `@$IP` is an *argument with which* you'd like to execute it. You can do as has been elsewhere suggested and simply split the token in two combined with a shell function - this is simply done. Or you can get the first token to *split itself*.

An interesting thing about shell `$var` names is they are pretty explicit about what characters they can contain. Save a single special case, `@` is not among those. If I do:

```
$var_this_is_appended_to_the_name
```

The shell will interpret the entire string as a single variable name because all of the characters within are allowable within a `$var` name. But...

```
$var@this_is_appended_to_the_name
```

...results in *two tokens (if not necessarily two **words**)* and the shell expands `$var` independently of *@the_rest*. Alias expansion, unfortunately, has no such convenient marker as `$` and so the shell will always attempt to expand either...

```
alias@this_is_appended; alias_this_is_appended
```

...as a single token. It is also because the shell expands both `$var` and `aliased cmdstring` simultaneously that the latter cannot be contained within the former and still be executed without `eval` - but then any arguments given `$var` - even `${varcontains='$(cmd substitutions)'}` will be evaluated *twice* - which can be fairly dangerous.

So I propose you do something with a `readonly` variable named `$ssh` that looks like this:

```
ssh() { case "$1" in
(@*)  set -- "$USER$@";;
esac; command -p ssh "$@"
}

readonly ssh='ssh '
```

That way you can do...

```
$ssh@someplace.com; $ssh@000.000.000.000
```

...or...

```
ssh @someplace.com
```

...and etc. or whatever, because the shell will split out the two tokens which are `$ssh` and `@somplace.com` into two *words*. It does not work, however, if you...

```
"$ssh@someplace.com"
```

...because in that case, though you get two tokens, the result is still single word. I used `readonly` above to ensure that the `$ssh` varname cannot be sabotaged and reset to something more dangerous, but this might still be possible to do with the `ssh` function for any normal user in the shell. I'm unaware of any means that can be used to `readonly` a shell function, but, if this is a concern for you, then you may want to locate the function in a `$PATH`ed shell script with appropriate read/write rights.

Then again, it can work without a function at all if set from a profile file or whatever:

```
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ readonly "ssh=ssh $USER"
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ $ssh@localhost
mikeserv@localhost's password:
```

But it is less flexible that way.

Answer (score 3):

Bash aliases [don't work that way](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) - they're simple word strings with no shell metacharacters and no globbing. you can, with a lot of effort, make the debug hook do what you want (start from [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command)), but you'd probably be better acclimatising to typing an extra couple of characters and defining a one-argument function `s` or something instead:

```
s() {
    ssh user@"$1"
}
```

Then:

```
s 127.0.0.1
```

will run:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1
```

It is technically possible to define individual aliases, or make individual shell scripts, that do what you want, but there are 2^32 possible addresses, so it's not really viable. If you have a very small number of addresses you may want to use, and you know them in advance, you can do that straightforwardly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can take advantage of the `command_not_found_handle` hook, since a bare IP address is extremely unlikely to be a valid command name. Add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ $1 =~ [0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        ssh user@$1
    else
        printf "Command not found: %s\n" "$1" >&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```

If the missing command matches your regular expression for an IP address, it will instead run the desired `ssh` command; otherwise, it mimics the default behavior for a missing command.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pattern matching in aliases. So if you want to login to `192.168.0.2` without typing `ssh user@` before that you have to specify:

```
alias 10.32.44.225="ssh user@10.32.44.225"
```

for each and every IP address you are likely to use.

Of course you can write a program to write those lines out for the range that you need. Or do something like:

```
for i in $(seq 225 228); do
    alias 10.32.44.$i="ssh user@10.32.44.$i"
done
```

to get aliases for the range `10.32.44.225` → `10.32.44.228`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simpler to use `ssh`'s config file, rather than a shell alias or function. Suppose `ssh user@10.32.44.225` connects you to your development machine. You might add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host dev
    User user
    Hostname 10.32.44.225
```

Now you can connect to the machine as `user` with

```
ssh dev
```

You can add more such aliases if you have multiple machines; see `man ssh_config` for more details.